# I need to access instances of a class outside the main function C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a little problem in my C#.Net program... i have a JSON file with a count value that indicates me how many values i'm going to store into my "object array"... after reading that value i need x instances of the class that i created to store the values... the problem is... how do i access those instances outside the main form function to use them in one of my event functions since i can't make global instances of the class cause my counter is inside the function and even if it was global i have other operations inside my main form function that need to be executed right after declaring my objects...

Here is the code...

```
public CurrencyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int count = 0;
        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json");
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        string text;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            text = sr.ReadLine();
            while (!text.Contains("count"))
            {
                text = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            count = CurrencyUtilities.getCount(text);
        }
        Currency[] currency = new Currency[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            currency[i] = new Currency();
        ...
    }

 private void SelectCurrency1_onItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SelectCurrency1.selectedValue != "USD")
            {
                int i = 0;
                //while (!currency[i].Name.Contains(SelectCurrency1.selectedValue))
                //  i++;
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance to anyone anyway!

Comment: Use a List in the class scope: `private List<Currency> Currencies = new List<Currency>();`. Then, in your functions, just use the list. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why don't you just use `Newtonsoft.Json` which will de-serialize the array for you? That's the standard way in c# now

Comment: @NikxDa you're saying that instead of using an object array a should use a list and push inside my objects right? i never used a list before... i'm going to try

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto but how can i deserialize it outside of my main function then?

Comment: @MurtasManuel You don't need to, you just need to keep the reference outside of the function's scope (like in the class's scope)

Comment: You should go and read up on scopes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Comment: @NikxDa yes... i should definetly read more about lists now... thank you for the advice!

Comment: Absolutely no problem. Consider giving my answer an upvote if it helped you out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are not aware about the value in `count` until it is populated, in such cases you should prefer `List<T>` instead for array, and you should keep that variable in global section so that you can easily access them.

```
private List<Currency> CurrencyList = new List<Currency>();
public CurrencyForm()
{
   // Your logic here 
   while (!text.Contains("count"))
   {
        CurrencyList.Add(new Currency());
   }
}
```

As a reference [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/221892/should-i-use-a-list-or-an-array) you can find few notes on comparison about List and arrays.

Comment: @MurtasManuel: Glad to hear that, Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. **Use a `List<Currency>` in your class scope.** This will function as a collection with variable Length. You can create it directly in the class scope and then add your elements to it from the function.
   Example: `private List<Currency> CurrencyList = new List<Currency>();`. You can then add to the list via `CurrencyList.Add (item);`
2. **Use the array you are already using**, but define it in the class scope and create the instance from your function. Then, access the array from the event function.

I'd go with the first approach because it is much more streamlined.